# GPX editors see empty folder

Tags: applications, file-management, gps-tracking, osmand

I have some gpx tracks recorded using OsmAnd. I can see the files using my browser and also the app "GPX Viewer" can load the files and display the tracks on a map. They are located on my external sd card at

(...) /Android/data/net.osmand/files/tracks/rec

However when I want to open the tracks in an editor, to change them, the "tracks" folder shows empty. This happens with all three apps I've tried: "GPX Track Editor",  "Rambler GPX Editor" and "Simple Track Editor."

Any suggestions?

Comment: check if there is a `.nomedia` file in that folder. If yes, delete and try again. I don't know if it helps in your case but for media , it does

Comment: Thanks, but no such file

Comment: If on Marshmallow or above, it could be that the editors did not request your consent to access the external SD via the DocumentProvider, which is mandatory.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman My android version is 7.0 so it looks like it could be yes. If so is there something to do about it or is that just a bug in (all three) apps? EDIT: I notice they have "storage" permission, is that enough for the sd card?

Comment: @jorgen Storage permission allows them to read and write on the internal storage only. It is not a proper bug, but if they are too old, they most likely are not patched to work with Android's mechanism. If your device is rooted, there may be a way, but if not, the only way is to move the track you wish to edit on your internal storage, edit it, and put it back where it was.